# Display values from String [] args

Tags: java, methods, program-entry-point

I have started to learn JAVA and I learnt that the main method

```
public static void main (String [] chpt)
```

ARGS often written fondly by coders can also be written changed to any word you want. ARGS or CHPT in my declaration is supposed to be an array. How can I view the contents of this array?
I tried

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(chpt)); and
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(chpt));
```

This is the entire program

```
public class Dislpy{    
static int square(int num) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return num *num;

}
public static void main(String[] chpt) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int num = 12;

    int counter = chpt.toString().length();
    System.out.println("Squared is " +square(num) +" " +counter);
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(chpt));
     for (int i = 0; i<= counter; i++){
        System.out.println("over here "+chpt.toString().indexOf(i));
    }
   }
}
```

but it didn't work and the output is

```
Squared is 144 27
[]
Over here -1.................this line was printed 27 times.
```

What is 27? What does 27 signify here? As @peeskillet mentioned in his answer there are no arguments being passed through command line hence it wont display any arguments.

I would like to access the contents of chpt array. Help me understand this better. Thanks, Cheers!

The output as displayed in Eclipse
[image: designmonks]

Comment: Congratulations, what's your question?

Comment: I am sorry, I accidentally clicked enter before writing my entire question. Could the negative vote be reversed please?

Comment: You need to actually pass arguments to it before any array is populated

Comment: Done, vote reverted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Updated answer

This works:

```
public static void main(String[] chpt) {
    int counter = Integer.parseInt(chpt[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i <= counter; i++) {
        System.out.println("over here " + square(i));
    }
}

over here 0
over here 1
over here 4
over here 9
```

### Array length

The magic 27 from your code is String length, not Array size:

```
chpt.toString().length() == 27
"[Ljava.lang.String;@5dcba031".length() == 27
```

The proper way is

```
System.out.println(chpt.size());
```

### Printing arrays

With arrays it is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(args));
}
```

args is primitive type `String[]`

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));
```

and whent printed results with something like:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@5dcba031
```

but after conversion to list"

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));
```

prints all elements nicely

Comment: I've improved the question and also added an image of the output. Could you check it out and clarify my doubt?

Comment: Hi. I added the arguments at command line and displayed it thanks, but my I have a doubt. Is it write to assume that the default array size is 27 bytes, am I correct? Why does the output show 27, what does the number 27 signify?

Comment: No, this is length of string `chpt.toString()` -> `[Ljava.lang.String;@5dcba031` (27 chars). The array `chpt` has length 1, print it with `System.out.println(chpt.length());`

Comment: I've written counter=chpt.toString().length(); sysout for counter is 27. In the code what is the number 27?

Comment: `"[Ljava.lang.String;@5dcba031".length() == 27`, to be sure print `System.out.println(chpt.toString());`

Comment: I did as you said. Sysout (chpt.toString.length()); the output of this line is 27 and sysout (chpt.length()) output is 3; What do these numbers mean?

Comment: chpt.toString() is always 27, this is char like this '[Ljava.lang.String;@5dcba031`. Print it. 3 mean you have 3 arguments passed to `main();` method. To print array use `System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.asList(args));`

Answer (score 2):

```
for (String argument : chpt) {
    System.out.println(argument);
}
```

Comment: or in one line: `System.out.println(Arrays.asList(chpt));`

Comment: Hi. I've added an image of the output and the program, could you take a look at it.

Comment: I'm going on a limb and assuming that the default array size has to be 27 bytes, am I correct? Why does the output show 27, what does the number 27 signify?

Answer (score 1):

Run this test

file TestClass.java

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        if (args.length == 0){
            System.out.println("You need at least one arg dummy!");
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            for (String s : args){
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Save the file as TestClass.java
>   Go to your command line and go to the directory of the java file and type:
>   **`javac TestClass.java`**
>   Then type:
>   **`java TestClass "Hello, world!" "Hello, Dummy!" "Where are my Dragons?!"`**

See what you get.

Each argument passed to the command line is separated by a space. If I left the quotation marks out, there would be 8 arguments instead of 3.

Comment: Hi. I am able to get the total number of arguments. Is it possible to display the contents of Chpt? I tried your method and it didn't work. I've added an image with the output shown.

Comment: Is it write to assume that the default array size is 27 bytes, am I correct? Why does the output show 27, what does the number 27 signify?

Answer (score 0):

just try this

```
for(String s : chpt){
   System.out.println(s);
}
```

this is not only for String[] args. for all Iterable ..

Comment: Well, tehnically for all Iterables. Arrays, Lists, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
String [] chpt// would print out [] as it contains no values nor are values added to it.
```

Answer (score -1):

You'd like a method that would print every single index of the String array, i.e.

```
public static void printStringArray(String[] myArray){
    for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
        System.out.println(myArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: [for each](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) is better, use java 7 :)

Comment: Nevertheless, there's nothing wrong with iterating explicitly. I don't think this warranted a downvote.

Comment: What's the benefit of using `foreach` over a `for-loop`? I was never really told that either has any pitfalls or benefits to each other.

Comment: If that's the only benefit, then I'll rightfully just stay with `for-loops`.

Comment: Or maybe go to more verbose language like COBOL :) Simplicity mean `easier to read`. Code is read many more times than written. Additional variables like `int i` is waste.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage benefit of using `foreach` over a `for-loop`: beautifies your code, easier to read, no issues with the iterator which can cause a `IndexOutOfBoundsException` or `NoSuchElementException`.